# nginx linux Virtual Host not working properly with example.com

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Virtual Host not working

i created a virtual host in nginx ubuntu for example.com
but when i go to example.com it shows the original example.com

This a virtual host file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

This is nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

**nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)**

**Ubuntu version**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to put example.com in /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

This overrules the DNS as set for the real example.com and will make your computer go to the local version instead of the original

```
sudo echo '127.0.0.1  example.com' >> /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the `example.com` file in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and place the following in it

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com/;
    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

Now symlink this file to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com`

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com
```

after restarting nginx it should be work.

```
nginx -s reload
```

for any debug :

```
nginx -t
```